# error install fusion pbx psql can not connect to server

Tags: fusionpbx

I am trying to install fusionpbx but i have error connecting to posgresql, i used the default installer published on their website

```
Install PostgreSQL
Install PostgreSQL and create the database and users

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
postgresql-client is already the newest version (13+225).
sudo is already the newest version (1.9.5p2-3+deb11u1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
ERROR:  role "fusionpbx" does not exist
ERROR:  role "freeswitch" does not exist
psql: error: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "10.147.20.2" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
error: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "10.147.20.2" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?<br/>psql: error: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "10.147.20.2" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
psql: error: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "10.147.20.2" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
psql: error: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "10.147.20.2" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
error: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "10.147.20.2" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?<br/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that PostgreSQL is already installed on your system but the roles for the database users "fusionpbx" and "freeswitch" have not been created yet.

using the following steps:

Open the PostgreSQL prompt by running the following command:

```
sudo -u postgres
```

Create the "fusionpbx" role with the following command:

```
CREATE ROLE fusionpbx WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'password';
```

Replace 'password' with a strong password that you choose.

Create the "freeswitch" role with the following command:

```
CREATE ROLE freeswitch WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'password';
```

Replace 'password' with a strong password that you choose.

Grant the necessary permissions to the "fusionpbx" and "freeswitch" roles by running the following commands:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE fusionpbx TO fusionpbx;

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE freeswitch TO freeswitch;
```

These commands will grant full privileges to the respective roles for their databases.

After completing these steps, you should be able to connect to the PostgreSQL server and use the "fusionpbx" and "freeswitch" roles to create the necessary databases for your FusionPBX installation.